# Get multiple emails between two characters sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my table, there is a column that populates as such

```
[0 email123@provider.com Y There was a internet issue 1 email234@provider.com N N/A 2 email345@provider.com Y My refrigerator short circuited my home.]
```

Is it possible to extract all the emails found here? I was thinking if its even possible to just extract everything besides the domain, so extracting the text between the ' ' and '@'.

Preferred expected result: `[email123@provider.com, email234@provider.com, email345@provider.com]`

Another result could be: `[email123, email234, email345]`

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `string_split()`:

```
select s.value as email
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.column, ' ') s
where s.value like '%@%.%'
```

This is, of course, an approximation.  But it should do a good enough job distinguishing emails from other words.

You can create a string using `string_agg()`:

```
select t.*, s.emails
from t outer apply
     (select string_agg(s.value, ',') as emails
      from string_split(t.column, ' ') s
     ) s
where s.value like '%@%.%'
```

Comment: To improve on Gordon's response, I used this query to move all emails in one line: `select STRING_AGG(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),s.value), ' ') as email
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.column, ' ') s
where s.value like '%@%.%'`

Comment: @Stefano . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: I accepted the answer again. I noticed there are limitations with other strings I'm working with. Applying your solution to those strings does not give the accurate solution. I did find another route to get the value. I may post another ticket when I get a chance. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Stefano . . . You can ask a new question with more appropriate sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below approach to get the full emails

```sql
;WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '[0 email123@provider.com Y There was a internet issue 1 email234@provider.com N N/A 2 email345@provider.com Y My refrigerator short circuited my home.]' AS Path
),
cte_onlyfullemails as
(
SELECT value as val
from yourTable
cross apply 
string_split(Path,' ')
)
select * from cte_onlyfullemails where CHARINDEX('@',val) > 0
```

```
+-----------------------+
|          val          |
+-----------------------+
| email123@provider.com |
| email234@provider.com |
| email345@provider.com |
+-----------------------+
```